# How do I debug a remote application in my eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

I am running my server from outside of my eclipse and now i want to debug it. so is it possible ?
If yes how can i do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) Specify this option on remote JVM.

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

Note that now the debug server is running at this remote host and port 5005.

2) In Eclipse, create and run remote debug config under [Run > Debug> Debug Configurations... > Remote Java Application](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html).