# Connect to embedded tomcat from IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, maven, intellij-idea, embedded-tomcat-7

I'm running tomcat as:

```
mvn tomcat7:run-war
```

I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422125/how-to-set-agentlib-property-for-mvn-tomcat-plugin-jpda) that I can set parameters for debugging.
By exporting maven option:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
mvn tomcat7:run-war
```

My first question, how can i connect to tomcat from IntelliJ IDEA? As usual I first configure tomcat itself in IDEA, but when I run it as embedded, there is no the application server at the moment I start it.

My second qustion, can I set MAVEN_OPTS in file, in order to skip running export command?
I've read that in pom.xml it is impossible. But I found [here](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Maven-s-memory-How-to-avoid-adding-the-MAVEN-OPTS-variable-td124888.html) that I can use the `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\mavenrc_pre.bat` file for this purpose. But I cannot find anything about this file usage in my books about maven. Don't you know, does it work? 
In order to check it, first I need to resolve the first problem with connecting to tomcat from idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To connect to a tomcat from IDEA:

- setup a "Remote" run configuration and specify the port you need to connect (here 8000)

[image]

Comment: As an alternative options, there is a way to debug Maven plugin goals from IDEA itself. Maven Projects tab -> Plugins -> tomcat7 -> tomcat7:run -> Debug

Comment: @Alexandr, I guess you mean tomcat7:run-war. Anyway this a neat solution that deserve to be posted as a separate answer. You got my vote anyway.