# How to debug spring-maven web application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am new to spring and maven and I have one web application. I want to debug that application ,I have applied the breakpoints but still when I use debug application it doesn't come on the breakpoints.
Can any 1 please tell how can i debug my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess: Are you running your project (with breakpoints) in DEBUG mode? Because if you use RUN mode - breakpoints won't be hit.

Comment: Yes I am running my project in debug mode in configuration I have used "tomcat:run"

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422125/how-to-set-agentlib-property-for-mvn-tomcat-plugin-jpda

Answer (score 0):

to enable debug mode you have 2 options:
1- use your server from the IDE for ex. eclipse in debug mode.
2- use remote debugging check this link http://davidsblog.eu/remote-debugging-of-tomcat-using-eclipse/

if you are using embedded servlet container as maven plugins you have to configure it for remote debugging as in above link

Comment: I am using Eclipse and in eclipse I am using tomcat server I can run my program directly from eclipse but i want to debug it so please tell what should I write in configuration so that it ll debug the program like for running tomcat program i am using "tomcat:run "